# Clicking on a div with class that is compound

Tags: selenium, click

I'm having trouble when trying to click on a link that has class which name is compound.The HTML on the page is :

```
<tr>
    <td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
        <div class="gwt-HTML h23 LNsel">
            <strong>Кутия (4)</strong>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I use

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class=gwt-HTML h23 LNsel]")).click()
```

The problem is that this is not working , I tried different ways.Question is how should i click on **Кутия (4)**.

Cheers,

Comment: Where is the question? Don't let us guess what you're struggling with.

Comment: Hi Jacek , the problem is that this is not working , I tried different ways.Question is how should i click on <strong>Кутия (4)</strong>. Cheers!

Comment: Add it to the question (edit it and copy the comment), so people will know the problem.

Comment: can u try driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='gwt-HTML h23 LNsel']")).click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing called "not working". Please describe exact behaviour or post exception message and stractrace.

Meanwhile,

try use CSS selector as follow:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".gwt-HTML.h23.LNsel")).click()
```

Or find it using text

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[text()='Кутия (4)']")).click()
```

If you want to use XPath to match exact **order** of class names "gwt-HTML h23 LNsel", please add quotes to it. If there are class names in this element, please use `contains`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='gwt-HTML h23 LNsel']")).click()
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'gwt-HTML h23 LNsel')]")).click()
```

Comment: Hi, it worked with the last try - "driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'gwt-HTML h23 LNsel')]")).click()". Cheers !